# Is there a way to have temporary playlists in Spotify?

Tags: music, spotify

Using Spotify, I listen to a large selection of music and a large selection of playlists [The same happens with my  iTunes but that just filled my HD so I use Spotify].

I just want a way to have a temporary playlist such that if I see something I like I can say ,"Hey I like that !" let me add that to a temporary playlist so I can play it later. Right now I just copy the links to my clipboard and hold it there. But that disappears soon if I am working on other stuff and accidently close that window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest you can do right now is to star/favorite your music. You click on the star icon next to the track and it'll go into your starred tracks (it is under Library/Starred).

You might want to suggest this as a feature in Spotify's [suggestion box](http://getsatisfaction.com/spotify/products/spotify_suggestions_feature_requests).

Comment: Yea this is the closest way other than my drop to clipboard. The problem here though is that it mixed with my actual all time favorites. When I say "I like that" it is sort of the the moment liking , for example I see something and I might not even play the whole track maybe two seconds or none at all, I just want to keep track of it for the future. Not necessarily the all time favorite. I guess I can dump my favorites and use it as a temp instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can:

1. create a regular playlist,
2. name it *TO-LISTEN-LATER* or something similar
3. send or drag'n'drop track to this playlist.

Later you'll listen to these tracks and decide what to do with them (remove, move to other playlist, etc).

I know it's obvious, so I'm guessing you don't like something about this idea. Let me know what it is.